# Having problems with jquery to change price on onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, expressionengine

I'm trying to change the price of a product when the select option is changed.  I'm using expressionengine and the curly braces were breaking the code so I'm trying it a different way.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function thePrice(sel) {
        var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text.match(/(\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/);
        if (value[1]) {
            $('.price').text(value[1]);
        } else {
            alert('nope');
        }
    }
</script>
```

The price is changing when it finds the $00.00 but if it doesn't find it I want it to put "not found" or whatever.  I was using the alert to test it.

The first part of the code works, it's the part that checks if there's a value or not.  Here's the markup:

```
       {select onchange='thePrice(this)'} 

        <option {selected} value="{option_value}" >
        {option_name}({option_value}) {if option_price_numeric > 0}(<? $price = str_replace("$","","{product_price}");$opt_price = str_replace("$","","{option_price}");echo money_format("$%i",($price + $opt_price));?>){/if}
         </option>
         {/select}
```

and this is what it looks like live:

[image: option box]

Comment: You should probably add your HTML markup as well just to make sure that we know the selectors are correct.

Comment: So the issue is that the alert isn't firing? Are you getting any kind of error in the console?

Comment: No. Nothing in the console.

Comment: And the Alert is not firing?  Or are you receiving the alert?

Comment: Can you alert your value[1] right after its set?
`var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text.match(/(\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/); alert(value[1]);`  And let me know what value is alerted when the if statement works and then the value when the else statement is not working.

Comment: Why is 'select' and '/select' in curly brackets instead of pointy?  In this template what is your PHP parse order set to... input or output?